# AWS Lambda Access to XMLHttpRequest at '…' from origin 'localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I know this question might be duplicated, but none of the existing question point to anything I'm not doing...

I've deployed an API using the serverless framework on AWS Lambda, but I'm having trouble with CORS.

I'm doing a get request using `API` module from `aws-amplify` in a react frontend:

```
    async function getProfileItem() {
    return API.get('profile', '/getProfileItem', {
        body: {
            emailId: emailId
        }
    });
}
```

and I am getting the below error when calling the endpoint:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxxx.execute-api.region.amazonaws.com/prod/getProfileItem' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

**I have created three endpoints so far to `create`, `update` and `get` but its only the `get` endpoint that is not working!!**

Below is relevant part of my serverless.yml:

```
functions:
  create:
    handler: create.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: createProfile
          method: post
          cors: true
          authorizer: aws_iam

  get:
    handler: get.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: getPofileItem
          method: get
          cors: true
          authorizer: aws_iam

  update:
    handler: update.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: profile/flipPhotoFlag
          method: put
          cors: true
          authorizer: aws_iam
```

Not posting my backend code since the request is not even hitting the backend and is just failing in the browser. Any clue why this might be happening with only `get` method while the `create` and `update` are working just fine?